# Difference of Assign projection, Reproject Layer, and Define layer projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, wgs84, utm

I have a point layer and a polygon layer that are all in UTM51N projection but do not align. Just want to know when should I use Assign, Reproject, or Define.

Experimented with a polygon in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic, which is the project CRS since this polygon is the first layer I loaded. Target projection is UTM51N.

Reproject - aligned

Assign - not aligned

Define - not aligned

Save layer as - aligned

Using 3.4 so there is no "on the fly projection" feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that reproject changes the geometry coordinates.

---

Let me start with a Point layer, with one feature, wich geometry is a point located in *latitude = 1°*, *longitude = 2°*.

The geometry WKT is `POINT ( 1 2 )` and the layer is defined with CRS `EPSG:4326`.

And I have a custom projected CRS which map those coordinates to *x = 2000m*, *y = 1000m*.

If I reproject the layer to my custom CRS, the new geometry WKT will be `POINT (2000 1000)`, and the new layer will be defined with my custom CRS (e.g, `CUSTOM:100001`).

---

If I assign my custom CRS to the source layer without reproject it, the geometry WKT of the feature will remain `POINT ( 1 2 )`, but the layer will be defined in `CUSTOM:100001` CRS.

And in that CRS, *x = 1m*, *y = 2m* represent a point far away from my source point.

---

In QGIS 3, the project CRS is the QGIS 2 *on-the-fly* reprojection feature.

If the project has a CRS defined, all the layers will be reprojected on-the-fly to that CRS before show them in the map.

You can set *No projection* for the project CRS in its properties, and the layers will be shown in their own CRS.

In that case, both geometries `POINT ( 1 2 )` will be shown aligned, altought they are located in different places of the Earth. And `POINT ( 2000 1000 )` geometry will be shown far away from the source point, altought they are the same point but defined in different CRS.

---

*Save layer as*, when the target CRS is not the same as the source one, implies a *Reprojection*.

*Assign* and *Define* I think is the same, change the layer CRS without change the geometry coordinates.

Comment: This is very helpful. Quite hard to understand but I'm getting some of it. Thanks, Gabriel!