# Creating line between point layer and line layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, polyline-creation, virtual-layer, extend

My goal is to create a line layer that is derived from the distance between a point layer and a line layer. An example could be using a line layer representing a road and a point layer representing a home or telephone pole.

I would like to create a vector line that extends from the road line layer to the point layer. Is there a Plugin for this?

Comment: A good question, but I was wondering what have you tried so far? What are your ideas? What kind of similar topics/threads/articles have you considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer

go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the query

```sql
select p.id, l.id, 
       min(st_distance(p.geometry, l.geometry)) dist, 
       ST_ShortestLine(p.geometry, l.geometry) geometry
from myPointLayer p, myLineLayer l
group by p.id
order by st_distance(p.geometry, l.geometry) asc
```

The `group by` will ensure we get a single row for each row in layer1. Because we `order by` distance and keep the `min`, the group by will retain the 1st entry, i.e. the nearest one.

[image]

Comment: thanks for chiming in JGH, this looks simpler than writing a python script. What were the names on your two layers in you example?

Comment: @sudofizz In the text code in the answer (not the picture), replace `myPointLayer` and `myLineLayer ` with your names. (in the picture-code, the layers were named `p` and `l` so no need for an alias as in the text-code)

Comment: Appreciate the help with this as I am learning a lot right now! Have you ever experienced the generated lines extending out of the map area?

Comment: Make sure all 3 layers have the same CRS

Comment: Got it. Only issue I have now is aligning my layers to the same projection. My point layer is in 4326 and line layer is in 3857.. If i change either of them, they misalign.. Not sure how to trouble-shoot that issue.

Comment: don't `set` but rather `reproject` one of the layer CRS (see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351939/difference-of-assign-projection-reproject-layer-and-define-layer-projection-in))

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks for the help JGH!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120973/discussion-between-sudofizz-and-jgh).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use QGIS expressions to crease such lines. There are two ways to do that:

1. Use geometry generator for visualization purpose, without creating a new layer. For that, add a new symbol layer in the style panel and set it to `Geometry Generator / Linestring` (see screenshot below).
2. Create actual geometries on a new layer: `Menu Processing / Toolbolx / Geometry by expression`.

In both cases, use the expression on the points layer, use the same expression (on line 6, replace `'line'` with the name of your line-layer). Be aware that the `overlay_nearest` function is available since QGIS 3.16:

```
make_line (
    $geometry, 
    closest_point (
        array_first (
            overlay_nearest (
                'line' , 
                $geometry
            )
        ), 
    $geometry
    )
)
```

*The screenshot illustrates the first version of using the expression:*
[image]