# Calculating area and projection using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I am facing problem calculating area and projection in general, using QGIS 3.18.3.

preface: I am using EPSG: 32643 projected CRS. I aim to compute area and the result is fine correct in this image.
[image]
*Calculating Area on Bing Map using Measuring tool*

When I load another layer as shown in image (EPSG: 32643) then the coordinates changes to (lat,long) and the area also is incorrect. I am sure that this layer is in correct EPSG. Not sure why the coordinates displayed does not give Cartesian coordinates.
[image]
*The coordinates are not in (X,Y) format*

Attached is the associated information for the layer.
[image]
How to resolve this issue and get the coordinates in correct format?

Comment: Most questions in this topic are resolved when a previous error in projection definition is discovered. Please [Edit] the question to provide the bounding envelope of the data for each of the datasets.

Comment: that looks like they are 4326 not UTM43N

Comment: Looks like a classic *changed the CRS definition but kept the original coordinate values* problem.

Comment: Does changing the projection not change the extent into Cartesian coordinates as well? Also, does setting the `layer CRS->set to EPSG:32643` change only the units and keeps the extent in its original projection?

Comment: @amanjain "Setting" the CRS doesn't reproject. It only defines the context. The values will be the same, but now they'll reference a completely different origin and units.

Comment: appreciate  everyone's help. What is the way out? Defining the projection to EPSG:32643?

Comment: @spatial-user You need to read this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351939/difference-of-assign-projection-reproject-layer-and-define-layer-projection-in

Comment: Read also this for background: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814

Comment: Qgis does on-the-fly projection to the Basemap project. you can change this by clicking on the pros info (EPSG number) in the bottom right corner

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get tired of reprojection/CRS issues in QGIS I always move to R.  Here is a sample script I used for area calculations:

```
rm(list = ls()) #clears environment
cat("\014") #clears console

library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("~/Desktop/Carolyn Shapefiles") #change your filepath

##ETHIOPIA 
Ethiopia <-st_read("geo2_et1994_2007.shp") #Import Ethiopia shapefile, 
projectd in WGS 84

Ethiopia_UTM<-st_transform(Ethiopia, 20138) #Adinan / UTM Zone 38N
st_crs(Ethiopia_UTM) #confirm proper tranformation

Ethiopia_area_values <- st_area(Ethiopia_UTM)
Ethiopia_area_values

Ethiopia_UTM$sq_meters <- Ethiopia_area_values

##Once the dataframe is to your liking, export it with whatever name you 
want using the line below.  
#st_write(Ethiopia_UTM, "Ethiopia_UTM.shp")

##UGANDA 
Uganda <- st_read("geo3_ug2014.shp") #Import Uganda shapefile, projected 
in WGS 84

Uganda_UTM <- st_transform(Uganda, 21095) #Arc 1960 / UTM zone 35N
st_crs(Uganda_UTM) #confirm proper tranformation

Uganda_area_values <- st_area(Uganda_UTM)
Uganda_area_values

Uganda_UTM$sq_meters <- Uganda_area_values

##Once the dataframe is to your liking, export it with whatever name you 
want using the line below.  
#st_write(Uganda_UTM, "Uganda_UTM.shp")

##df1[c(1, 6, 2:5)] #sample of how to re-order the columns if you need`
```